# Embedde element restart on jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page is divided in 3 areas one on the left, one on the right and one in the middle, that normally is hidden.

Left part displays some contents like YouTube, Photosynth, Audio Media HTML5.

I created an action that moves contents into the middle area.

```
$('.iilVisualizerContainer').appendTo('#iilecJQuery');
```

Hiding the source div and unhiding the destination with animation that change the width.

The element with id `iilecJQuery` is an `iframe` that contains the media object like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Every time that I move the `iframe`, the content restarts.

Is possible to prevent this type of event?

Comment: content restart? you mean video restarts?

Comment: can you elaborate on 'Every time that i move the iframe'

Comment: This is a well known behaviour of iframe. AFAIK, there is no workaround for that behaviour.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Q6ZM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove from the DOM some elements, and append them again, it won't be the same DOM element, video from youtube will load again as it does when document is ready after body onload.

You might considere appending you're iframe in the body, and adjust position with css (absolute/relative).
You'll be able to animate your iframe as you wish, but don't remove it from the DOM